# Copying files / folders between user accounts

Tags: finder, user-account, dropbox, file-transfer

I have 2 admin user accounts on my Mac (both are mine).

There is a folder that I'd like to move from one of the accounts to the other. I tried simply locating the folder in Finder and then copying / pasting it into the other user folder.

I've set `read & write` to `everyone` and also `Apply to enclosed items`.

But it doesn't seem to play nicely with Dropbox, as it won't sync properly (see the 'x' icons next to each file). It says it doesn't have permission to access the files.

[image]

Comment: So you were able to move the files and folders you needed to successfully without an apparent problem. However, you are now having trouble with Dropbox processing them in their new location. Is that correct?

Comment: Are both admin users logged in simultaneously AND is Dropbox logged in by these two admin users?

Comment: @Alper yep thats correct

Comment: @IconDaemon not logged in at the same time no, also the account that I'm copying from doesn't have dropbox... although now I think about it, I could just log into dropbox from that account and sync everything that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Here an item can be a file or folder.

### How to Transfer an Item to Another User Without Having to Enter a Password.

This answer was tested using macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

If a user A wants to give a copy of an item to user B, then user A can do so by copying the item to user B's Drop Box (which is the `/Users/B/Public/Drop Box` folder). This may require holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key, if dragging and dropping the item to user B's Drop Box. User A may then elect to put the original item in the trash.

> Note: Having user A move an item to user B's Drop Box can result in User B having to enter a password in order to move the item to the trash. This is why copying should be used instead.

For user B to take ownership of the item, user B needs to copy the item from user B's Drop Box. This may require holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key, if dragging and dropping the item from user B's Drop Box. User B may then elect to move the item in user B's Drop Box to the trash.

> Note: Having user B move the item from user B's Drop Box will result in user A retaining ownership of the item. This is why copying should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've both with and without `sudo` but I get the following error: `zsh: bad substitution`

Comment: I change my answer to one that works and does not require using the Terminal.

Comment: I change my answer to one that does not require using the Terminal or entering passwords.